# Node.js 7 how to use sequelize transaction with async / await?

Tags: transactions, sequelize.js

Node.js 7 and up already support async/await syntax. How should I use async/await with sequelize transactions?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

```js
let transaction;    

try {
  // get transaction
  transaction = await sequelize.transaction();

  // step 1
  await Model.destroy({ where: {id}, transaction });

  // step 2
  await Model.create({}, { transaction });

  // step 3
  await Model.update({}, { where: { id }, transaction });

  // commit
  await transaction.commit();

} catch (err) {
  // Rollback transaction only if the transaction object is defined
  if (transaction) await transaction.rollback();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. `t` in this case is a Promise and not the transaction object.

Comment: @Pier, await waits the sequelize.transaction() and then get the result of it. the t is not the promise, it is the result of promise.

Comment: I can't seem to get await to work when I'm doing a .findOne() command.  Does it work with this?

Comment: user7403683 you are a champion... I will forever remember your name!

Comment: What if `transaction = await sequelize.transaction();` fails? Then `transaction.rollback()` will throw an error. Do we need to check whether .rollback is available on transaction in catch block?

Comment: @Kunal, there should be an "if (transaction)..." clause. I submitted a change request to the code example for peer review.

Comment: it is not working in my case untill i pass transaction as key:value. eg in above solution, {transaction:transaction} is working. I am using sequelize version 5.19.2

Answer (score 65):

The accepted answer is an "unmanaged transaction", which requires you to call `commit` and `rollback` explicitly. For anyone who wants a "managed transaction", this is what it would look like:

```js
try {
    // Result is whatever you returned inside the transaction
    let result = await sequelize.transaction( async (t) => {
        // step 1
        await Model.destroy({where: {id: id}, transaction: t});

        // step 2
        return await Model.create({}, {transaction: t});
    });

    // In this case, an instance of Model
    console.log(result);
} catch (err) {
    // Rollback transaction if any errors were encountered
    console.log(err);
}
```

To rollback, just throw an error inside the transaction function:

```js
try {
    // Result is whatever you returned inside the transaction
    let result = await sequelize.transaction( async (t) => {
        // step 1
        await Model.destroy({where: {id:id}, transaction: t});

        // Cause rollback
        if( false ){
            throw new Error('Rollback initiated');
        }

        // step 2
        return await Model.create({}, {transaction: t});
    });

    // In this case, an instance of Model
    console.log(result);
} catch (err) {
    // Rollback transaction if any errors were encountered
    console.log(err);
}
```

If any code that throws an error inside the transaction block, the rollback is automatically triggered.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been looking for this solution for a while. Didn't realize you could await `sequelize.transaction`.

Comment: @hellowill89 - you can check the documentation of a given function. If it returns a Promise, then you can use await.

Comment: `Property 'transaction' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/Users/mac/Projects/myinvoice-be/node_modules/sequelize/types/index")'. Did you mean 'Transaction'?ts(2551)
` I have imported sequelize from `import sequelize from 'sequelize';`

Comment: A nice answer for completeness i suppose but I don't know why I would want the indirection of throwing an error to rollback rather than explicitly just stating it. Maybe if you do it enough times its better but I prefer the explicit version myself.

Comment: @JoelM its because thats the only way to rollback in a managed transaction. There is no transaction.rollback.

Answer (score 10):

If CLS is enabled, Sequelize can use that to keep your transaction object and automatically pass it to all queries inside the `continuation-passing` cycle.

**Setup:**

```js
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";
import { createNamespace } from "cls-hooked"; // npm i cls-hooked

const cls = createNamespace("transaction-namespace"); // any string
Sequelize.useCLS(cls);

const sequelize = new Sequelize(...);
```

**Usage:**

```js
const removeUser = async (id) => {
    await sequelize.transaction(async () => { // no need `async (tx)`
        await removeUserClasses(id);
        await User.destroy({ where: { id } }); // will auto receive `tx`
    });
}

const removeUserClasses = async (userId) => {
    await UserClass.destroy({ where: { userId } }); // also receive the same transaction object as this function was called inside `sequelize.transaction()`
    await somethingElse(); // all queries inside this function also receive `tx`
}
```

**How it works?**

From Sequelize source code: `github.com/sequelize`

[Check and save transaction to CLS](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/edac3e9075f9daf70a9ae0681dd4a847db5cbc59/lib/transaction.js#L137)

```js
if (useCLS && this.sequelize.constructor._cls) {
    this.sequelize.constructor._cls.set('transaction', this);
}
```

[Retrieve transaction from CLS and set to options](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/lib/sequelize.js#L631)

```js
if (options.transaction === undefined && Sequelize._cls) {
    options.transaction = Sequelize._cls.get('transaction');
}
```

**Read more:**

1. [Sequelize: automatically pass transactions to all queries](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/transactions.html#automatically-pass-transactions-to-all-queries)
2. [CLS hooked](https://github.com/Jeff-Lewis/cls-hooked)
3. [Async Hooks](https://nodejs.org/api/async_hooks.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for posting an example using CLS. Clean.

Answer (score 7):

The answer given by user7403683 describes async/await way for unmanaged transaction (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/transactions.html#unmanaged-transaction-then-callback-)

Managed transaction in async/await style may look as follows:

```
await sequelize.transaction( async t=>{
  const user = User.create( { name: "Alex", pwd: "2dwe3dcd" }, { transaction: t} )
  const group = Group.findOne( { name: "Admins", transaction: t} )
  // etc.
})
```

If error occurs, the transaction is automatically rolled back.

Comment: No need of try, catch ?

Answer (score 3):

The above code has an error in destroy call.

```
 await Model.destroy({where: {id}, transaction});
```

Transaction is part of the options object.

Answer (score 0):

```
async () => {
  let t;

  try {
    t = await sequelize.transaction({ autocommit: true});

    let _user = await User.create({}, {t});

    let _userInfo = await UserInfo.create({}, {t});

    t.afterCommit((t) => {
      _user.setUserInfo(_userInfo);
      // other logic
    });
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//try with this

```js
const transaction = await sequelize.transaction({ autocommit: false });
    try {
      await Model.create(data, {transaction})
    } catch (e) {
      if (transaction) await transaction.rollback();
      next(e);
      response.status(500).json({ error: e });
    }

    if (transaction) {
      await transaction.commit();
    }
```